# R shiny passing reactive to selectInput choices

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In a shiny app (by RStudio), on the *server* side, I have a reactive that returns a list of variables by parsing the content of a `textInput`. The list of variables is then used in `selectInput` and/or `updateSelectInput`.

I can't make it work. Any suggestions?

I have made two attempts. The first approach is to use the reactive `outVar` directly into `selectInput`. The second approach is to use the reactive `outVar` in `updateSelectInput`. Neither works.

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {

    outVar <- reactive({
        vars <- all.vars(parse(text=input$inBody))
        vars <- as.list(vars)
        return(vars)
    })

    output$inBody <- renderUI({
        textInput(inputId = "inBody", label = h4("Enter a function:"), value = "a+b+c")
    })

    output$inVar <- renderUI({  ## works but the choices are non-reactive
        selectInput(inputId = "inVar", label = h4("Select variables:"), choices =  list("a","b"))
    })

    observe({  ## doesn't work
        choices <- outVar()
        updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "inVar", choices = choices)
    })

})
```

#### ui.R

```
shinyUI(
  basicPage(
    uiOutput("inBody"),
    uiOutput("inVar")
  )
)
```

A short while ago, I posted the same question at shiny-discuss, but it has generated little interest, so I'm asking again, with apologies, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/e0MgmMskfWo

**Edit 1**

@Ramnath has kindly posted a solution that appears to work, denoted *Edit 2* by him. But that solution does not address the problem because the `textinput` is on the `ui` side instead of on the `server` side as it is in my problem. If I move the `textinput` of Ramnath's second edit to the `server` side, the problem crops up again, namely: nothing shows and RStudio crashes. I found that wrapping `input$text` in `as.character` makes the problem disappear.

**Edit 2**

In further discussion, Ramnath has shown me that the problem arises when the server attempts to apply the dynamic function `outVar` before its arguments have been returned by `textinput`. The solution is to first check whether `is.null(input$inBody)` exists.

***Checking for existence of arguments is a crucial aspect of building a shiny app***, so why did I not think of it? Well, I did, but I must have done something wrong! Considering the amount of time I spent on the problem, it's a bitter experience. I show after the code how to check for existence.

Below is Ramnath's code with `textinput` moved to the `server` side. It crashes RStudio so don't try it at home. (I have used his notation)

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    uiOutput('textbox'),  ## moving Ramnath's textinput to the server side
    uiOutput('variables')
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    outVar <- reactive({
      vars <- all.vars(parse(text = input$text))  ## existence check needed here to prevent a crash
      vars <- as.list(vars)
      return(vars)
    })

    output$textbox = renderUI({
      textInput("text", "Enter Formula", "a=b+c")
    })

    output$variables = renderUI({
      selectInput('variables2', 'Variables', outVar())
    })
  }
))
```

The way I usually check for existence is like this:

```
if (is.null(input$text) || is.na(input$text)){
  return()
} else {
  vars <- all.vars(parse(text = input$text))
  return(vars)
}
```

Ramnath's code is shorter:

```
if (!is.null(mytext)){
  mytext = input$text
  vars <- all.vars(parse(text = mytext))
  return(vars)
}
```

Both seem to work, but I'll be doing it Ramnath's way from now on: maybe an unbalanced bracket in my construct had earlier prevented me to make the check work? Ramnath's check is more direct.

Lastly, I'd like to note a couple of things about my various attempts to debug.

In my debugging quest, I discovered that there is an option to "rank" the priority of "outputs" on the server side, which I explored in an attempt to solve my problem, but didn't work since the problem was elsewhere. Still, it's interesting to know and seems not very well known at this time:

```
outputOptions(output, "textbox", priority = 1)
outputOptions(output, "variables", priority = 2)
```

In that quest, I also *tried* `try`:

```
try(vars <- all.vars(parse(text = input$text)))
```

That was pretty close, but still did not fix it.

The first solution I stumbled upon was:

```
vars <- all.vars(parse(text = as.character(input$text)))
```

I suppose it would be interesting to know why it worked: is it because it slows things down enough? is it because `as.character` "waits" for `input$text` to be non-null?

Whatever the case may be, I am extremely grateful to Ramnath for his effort, patience and guidance.

Comment: `renderUI` is used for input elements that change dynamically. In your case, the `textInput` is better placed in the UI, since there are no dynamic elements involved.

Comment: @ Ramnath, this is a stripped-down example: I do have dynamic elements in my setup  :-)

Comment: On the very first line of my question, I wrote on the __server__ side. If you read my code, you'll see that it covers all the usual situations. It is odd that one needs to wrap the input with `as.character` on the `server` side but not on the `ui` side. Would you consider that a bug? Or is that a feature you would have expected? Oh! someone downvoted, oh well ...

Comment: It is not a bug. If you first check whether `input$inBody` exists before doing the `all.vars` call, it still works. So it is not the `as.character` that really matters. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/76c98dde2e4c87073239) with what I mean.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need to use `renderUI` on the server side for dynamic UIs. Here is a minimal example. Note that the second drop-down menu is reactive and adjusts to the dataset you choose in the first one. The code should be self-explanatory if you have dealt with shiny before.

```
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', c('mtcars', 'iris')),
    uiOutput('columns')
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$columns = renderUI({
      mydata = get(input$dataset)
      selectInput('columns2', 'Columns', names(mydata))
    })
  }
))
```

EDIT. Another Solution using `updateSelectInput`

```
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', c('mtcars', 'iris')),
    selectInput('columns', 'Columns', "")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    outVar = reactive({
      mydata = get(input$dataset)
      names(mydata)
    })
    observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, "columns",
      choices = outVar()
    )})
  }
))
```

EDIT2: Modified Example using `parse`. In this app, the text formula entered is used to dynamically populate the dropdown menu below with the list of variables.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    textInput("text", "Enter Formula", "a=b+c"),
    uiOutput('variables')
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    outVar <- reactive({
      vars <- all.vars(parse(text = input$text))
      vars <- as.list(vars)
      return(vars)
    })

    output$variables = renderUI({
      selectInput('variables2', 'Variables', outVar())
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thanks Ramnath, my problem is a little different I think. I've been successful doing what you do here with `names()` in another app. But here I'm trying to pass `outVar()` to `selectInput()`, where `outVar()` outputs a reactive list. It might be a problem with `outVar()`, but I don't see what, or a problem of timing in the sequence of events. Maybe it's a silly mistake too. Do you see something wrong in my code? Do I need to be explicit about `names()` or about `get()`? Thanks!

Comment: If I write `return(list("a","b"))` right at the top of `outVar()` then it works. But if I leave the code as given above and look in the console, then `str(outVar())` returns exactly what `str(list("a","b"))` returns (visually speaking), so I think mine is a problem of timing. The `outVar()` is not ready at the time `selectInput()` needs the `choices`, could that be the problem?

Comment: AFAIK, if you need dynamic UI elements, you need to either use `renderUI` or an `updateSelectInput` method. This overcomes the timing problem that you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks Ramnath, my code above has an `updateSelectInput` method, but it's not working. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem I have is related to the sequence of steps, I tried setting `outputOptions(output, "inBody", 1)` and `outputOptions(output, "inVar", 2)` in the hope that `updateSelectInput` would have the patience to wait for `outVar()` to be ready, but it makes no difference, so perhaps the problem is elsewhere.  Can you make an example with `parse` instead of a known list? Thanks for trying anyhow!

Comment: thanks again!  I just notice your second edit, after I wrote an answer to my own question. I'm not sure why your version works, because as far as I can see the only difference between the version in your second edit and the version I posted in my question is that your `textinput` is on the __ui__ side instead of on the __server__ side ... As I explain in my answer, I found that I had to wrap the `input$text` part in `as.character` for it to work on the server side...

Comment: just made an edit to my question explaining that the problem crops up when `textinput` is on the server side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to what to do if the `selectInput` is in a variableUI. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

## server.R

```
### This will create the dynamic dropdown list ###

output$carControls <- renderUI({
    selectInput("cars", "Choose cars", rownames(mtcars))
})


## End dynamic drop down list ###

## Display selected results ##

txt <- reactive({ input$cars })
output$selectedText <- renderText({  paste("you selected: ", txt() ,sep="") })


## End Display selected results ##
```

## ui.R

```
uiOutput("carControls"),
  br(),
  textOutput("selectedText")
```