# R Shiny: passing multiple, succesive reactives to selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying to extend the second solution posted by Ramnath (the one using `updateSelectInput`) in the problem originally posted at [R shiny passing reactive to selectInput choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465411/r-shiny-passing-reactive-to-selectinput-choices)  .  I'd like to allow the user to select inputs from a hierarchical series of inputs where the choice in each selection updates the possible values in the next selection.  As an example, in the following I modify Ramnath's code by simply adding a third input that lists the values of the variable selected in the second input.  This example is based on the `mtcars` and `iris` datasets, and was run on R v 3.1.1 and RStudio v 0.98.1062.  It doesn't throw an error but you'll see that I'm stuck on how to add a second `reactive()` that takes as its input a combination of `input$dataset` and `input$column`.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(

  ui = bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('dataset', 'Choose data set', c('mtcars', 'iris')),
    selectInput('columns', 'Choose variable', ""),
    selectInput('values', 'Show values', "")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session){

    # updates variable names based on selected dataset 
    outVar = reactive({
      names(get(input$dataset))
    })

    # i want this to update the values of the selected variable
    outVar2 = reactive({
      sort(unique(get(input$dataset)[, 2]))  # this works but of course I don't want the second variable every time
      #sort(unique(get(input$dataset)[, input$columns]))   # this fails but this is the idea I'm after
    })

    # i want these to update the UI based on the reactive output above 
    observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, "columns", choices = outVar())
      updateSelectInput(session, "values", choices = outVar2())
    })       
  }
))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [R shiny passing reactive to selectInput choices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465411/r-shiny-passing-reactive-to-selectinput-choices), one way to do what you want is to wrap the `selectInput` in a `renderUI` on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

Responding to my first ever question.  Seems this is old but since I've been playing around with Shiny for the past week, I figured I would help answer this one directly.

To answer the question directly, the `sort(unique(get(input$dataset)[, input$columns]))` statement doesn't fail, it is the `observe` statement. Because both `outVar()` and `outVar2()` are in the `observe` statement, the `observe` statement will run when either variable updates. Therefore, when a change to the second `selectInput` (the `input$columns` variable), it will actually cause the first `selectInput` to update via  `updateSelectInput(session, "columns", choices = outVar())`.

This then resets the column dropdown list back to the original choice, making it seem as if the application is broken.  To see this in slow motion, I would recommend adding a `browser()` call in the `observe` statement to how the code steps through:

```
observe({
  browser()
  updateSelectInput(session, "columns", choices = outVar())
  updateSelectInput(session, "values", choices = outVar2())
})
```

Overall, I broke up the `observe` statement into 2 `observeEvent` statements (I got errors when only breaking the statement up into two separate `observe` statements when I changed the dataset).  By wrapping the `updateSelectInput` functions in the `observeEvent` they will only try to run when the necessary input is actually updated as seen below:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(

  ui = bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('dataset', 'Choose data set', c('mtcars', 'iris')),
    selectInput('columns', 'Choose variable', ""),
    selectInput('values', 'Show values', "")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session){

    # updates variable names based on selected dataset 
    outVar = reactive({
      names(get(input$dataset))
    })

    # i want this to update the values of the selected variable
    outVar2 = reactive({
      if (input$columns == "") return()
      sort(unique(get(input$dataset)[, input$columns]))
    })

    # create separate observeEvents to 
    observeEvent(input$dataset, {
      updateSelectInput(session, "columns", choices = outVar())
    })

    observeEvent(input$columns, {
      updateSelectInput(session, "values", choices = outVar2())
    })

  }
))
```