# Data driven shiny inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I have been doing some research and im having a hard time finding out if it is possible to create a data driven input in Shiny. for example, i have a selectInput menu that has options [0,1,2] this is selecting the value of var1. if i was to allow the user to populate data which creates data for var1 with a value of 4, 4 would then be missing from the input menu. So my question in short is does anyone have any suggestions about how to create an input that is data driven i.e. it is able to read the dataset and see that var1 has the values of 0,1,2 and now 4 (from the user added data). It would then include 4 in the selectinput menu.

Any ideas/ suggestions would be greatly appreciated! p.s. i know this maybe difficult to do without code/ a working example, but im more or less asking about the theory of having inputs be data driven.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465411/r-shiny-passing-reactive-to-selectinput-choices

Comment: @jimbo thats what ive been looking for, not sure why i couldn't find it, thanks

Comment: glad i could be useful