# Issue in dynamic renderUI in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using renderUI() to display dynamic UI. The dropdown list boxes are updated dynamically but when I select a specific value from the drop down  it does the needful but falls back to the 1st element in the list. Why does this happen? Why cannot it stay at the value selected.

```
ui.R
fluidRow(
                            column(3,
                                   radioButtons("matchType", label = h3("Match type"),
                                                choices = list("Test" = "Test",
                                                               "ODI" = "ODI", 
                                                               "Twenty20" = "TT"), 
                                                inline=TRUE,
                                                selected = "Test"),
                                   uiOutput("players"),
                                   uiOutput("functions") 

                            ),

 server.R
 testBatsman <- c("X","Y","Z")
 odiBatsman <- c("XX","YY","ZZ")
 funcs <- c("A","B","C")
 funcsODITT <- c("AA","BB","CC")
 output$batsmanPlot <- renderPlot({  
    # Include the list to display in the drop downs on choice of matchType
    if(input$matchType == "Test"){
        player = testBatsman
        f = funcs
    } else if(input$matchType == "ODI"){
        player = odiBatsman
        f = funcsODITT
    }

    output$players = renderUI({
        selectInput('batsman', 'Columns',choices=player)
    })
    output$functions = renderUI({
        selectInput('batsmanFunc', 'Column1',choices=f)
    })

    print(input$batsman)
    analyzeBatsman(input$batsman,input$batsmanFunc,input$matchType)
```

While it is able to dynamically adjust the 2 drop downs it goes back to first element of the selected list. For e,g when
testBatsman('Z') and funcs('C") it displays this briefly before returing back to testBatsman('X') and funcs("A").

Why does this happen? How can I make it stay at the values selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following change and it seems to work now. It stays on the selected value.

```
output$batsmanPlot <- renderPlot({  
    # Include the list to display in the drop downs on choice of matchType
    if(input$matchType == "Test"){
        player = testBatsman
        f = funcs
    } else if(input$matchType == "ODI"){
        player = odiBatsman
        f = funcsODITT
    }
    else {
        player = ttBatsman
        f = funcsODITT
    }
output$players = renderUI({
    selectInput('batsman', 'Columns',choices=player,selected=input$batsman)
})
output$functions = renderUI({
    selectInput('batsmanFunc', 'Column1',choices=f,selected=input$batsmanFunc)
})
```