# Shiny conditionalPanel - different options based on preceding input

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a `conditionalPanel` that displays when a preceding `input` is filled out. I want the `conditionalPanel` to populate with choices based on the initial `input`.

My code looks something like this:

```
   selectInput("initialvalue", "Initial Value", c("Choose one" = "", as.character(initialvaluelist))),
   conditionalPanel(
     condition = "input.initialvalue=='First Option'",
     selectInput("conditionalchoices", "Conditional Choices", choices = c("Click to select from list" = "", firstoptionchoices), selected = NULL, multiple=TRUE)),
   conditionalPanel(
     condition = "input.initialvalue=='Second Option'",
     selectInput("conditionalchoices", "Conditional Choices", choices = c("Click to select from list" = "", secondoptionchoices), selected = NULL, multiple=TRUE))
```

In this example, choosing `First Option` would pull up `firstoptionchoices` and choosing `Second Option` would pull up `secondoptionchoices`.

This works in the UI, but only the first `conditionalPanel` condition updates the reactive variable. The second one does not. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'm not sure that you can have two different `selectInput` functions with the same identifier. Giving the same ID twice would create two HTML elements with the same ID which is invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks conrad-mac! Your comment helped me get unstuck. I was able to solve this issue by creating a reactive variable for the conditional choices, and I put the `selectInput` as a `renderUI` output, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465411/r-shiny-passing-reactive-to-selectinput-choices).

Comment: Hi Jeff, I think it could be useful if you change your last comment to be the answer and accept it. Obviously adding the code as example.