# Updating a selectInput based on previous selectInput flexdashboard

Tags: r, flexdashboard, shiny-reactivity

I have the following dashboard showing the database mtcars and first column the brand, I have two filters that are select input. My goal is that when filtering by brand, for example if the manufacturer is Mazda then the second model filter shows me only **Mazda RX4** and **Mazda RX4 Wag**. Any idea how to achieve it, thanks.

````
---
title: "mtcars dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r}
df <- mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("model") %>%
      mutate(brand = c("Mazda","Mazda","Datsun","AMC","AMC","Plymouth","Plymouth","Mercedez","Mercedez","Mercedez",
                     "Mercedez","Mercedez","Mercedez","Mercedez","Cadillac","Lincoln MC","Chrysler","Fiat","Honda","Toyota",
                     "Toyota","Dodge","AMC","Chevrolet","Pontiac","Fiat","Porsche","Lotus","Ford","Ferrari","Maserati","Volvo")) %>%
      select("brand","model", "mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec","vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

Select the **car brand** and **model** you want to observe:

The filter is dynamic, if you filter by a manufacturer, only the corresponding models will be shown.

```{r}
brand_mtcars <- c("all",unique(df$brand))
model_mtcars <- c("all",unique(df$model))

selectInput(inputId = "brand", label = h4(HTML("<i class='far fa-building'></i> Select Brand")), 
            choices = brand_mtcars, selected = "all", multiple = FALSE)

selectInput(inputId = "model", label = h4(HTML("<i class='fas fa-car'></i> Select model")), 
            choices = model_mtcars, selected = "all", multiple = FALSE)
```

Table {data-orientation=rows data-icon="fa-chart-bar"}
=====================================

```{r}
result <- reactive({
  condition1 <- if(input$brand == "all"){brand_mtcars[-1]} else{input$brand}
  condition2 <- if(input$model == "all"){model_mtcars[-1]} else{input$model}
  filter(df, brand %in% condition1 & model %in% condition2)
  })


DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(result(), options = list(pageLength = 20, dom = 'tip'))
  })
```
````

[image]

**My expected output**

For example: If you selected the Mazda brand it should look like this.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465411/r-shiny-passing-reactive-to-selectinput-choices).  The top answer suggests using `renderUI` to create dynamic UI based off previously selected data. Based off the link I gave, I wonder if you will have to incorporate for shiny syntax

Comment: @DanielJachetta I see that this is a guide but I am not sure how to incorporate the UI and Server in a flexdashboard.